# mysql connector error 1130: host not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I just upgraded to Verizon Fios internet this morning.  I have a python script that accesses a database on a MySQL (mariadb) server on a raspberrypi (both are on the same network).  It worked with my old internet/IP address, however now I am getting:

`mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1130: Host 'my_computer_name.myfiosgateway.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

Steps I took leading up to error:

1. Confirmed new IP address of computer running the script
2. Changed IP address in configuration file that the python script uses to new IP address
3. I created a new user in the mysql server with the new host IP address of the laptop running the script
4. Granted all privileges to the new user on the database on the server
5. Flushed privileges
6. Restarted the mysql server

I'm not sure why the error is returning the computer's name, and not the IP address, but I even did the above steps with the exact host name returned in the error and it's still not working.  I also compared the GRANTS on the MySQL server from the old IP address to the new one, and they are the same.

I'm able to ping the raspberrypi from my laptop with no issues.

Am I forgetting something?  Is there a setting I may have to change on my router?  That's the only thing that has changed from before when the script would work.

**dbConfig.py**

```
dbConfig = {
    'host': 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx',
    'database': 'NHL',
    'user': 'greg',
    'password': 'xxxxxx',
}
```

**Script that accesses database**

```
import dbConfig as guiConfig
import csv
import time

# connect to server
conn = mysql.connect(**guiConfig.dbConfig)
```

The bind-address in my .cnf file is commented out.

Comment: this has niothing to do with the python code per se, the server is configurd only to allow loacalhost or such things.  it is normal that mysql is cofigured secur to aölow omöy local host to access. also ia am wondering why you get an answer from the server are you using ssh or another tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the Laptop running the script has another IP address?

Since the TCP/IP connection to the database works, there must be something wrong with the created MariaDB user or it's privileges. You could set the following parameter in the `my.cnf` in order to skip the DNS resolving. This improves the connection performance and it seems to confuse you. You should then see the Source IP address of the connection.

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
```